# Five Historical Features

Tags: wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, history

> A type of boat, a font, a trek, a multi-country palace,
>   A brand of car that used to be, a guarantee or promise.
>   All of us are reside in France but three of us are foreign
>   For two of us are from the States and one of us is Roman.
>   Beneath the ground you may find one, the last perhaps in granite
>   How judo holds out anagram, we're surgery and planet.
>   Three nations split the five of us, each had blood spilled upon her.
>   We're famous now in history, a day named in our honor

Comment: Fortnightly topic challenge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm thinking this is referencing

> the Allied Invasion of Normandy

All of us are reside in France but three of us are foreign
For two of us are from the States and one of us is Roman.

> The 5 beaches; Utah, Omaha, and Juno are foreign

Beneath the ground you may find one, the last perhaps in granite

> Gold, and Sword - Sword in the Stone?

How judo holds out anagram,

> Gold, Juno, Sword, Omaha, Utah

we're surgery and planet.

> Operation Neptune

Three nations split the five of us, each had blood spilled upon her.

> U.S., U.K, Canada

We're famous now in history, a day named in our honor

> 'D-Day'

After getting all that, the first two lines start coming together

> Maybe U-boat and Tahoma can make Utah, Oma- Haj could be a trek, -word is likely the last one, leaving unogolds for palace and car. unog could be United Nations Office: Geneva, with the car being an Olds, short for Oldsmobile?

I feel much less confident about this analysis then the other several lines though, perhaps I'm forcing it.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that was it. Congratulations!

Comment: For the second last, see where it is housed.